# Omit foreign key values from child elements when exporting from Access to XML

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two tables CR and RELEASE with relationship from CR (ID) to RELEASE (CRID) one to many.

CR (design):

```
ID: key, unique
Description: text
```

RELEASE (design):

```
ID: key, unique
CRID: number, not unique
Name: text
```

With the following VBA code, I am managed to export the tables to XML.

```
Set objOrderInfo = Application.CreateAdditionalData
objOrderInfo.Add ("RELEASE")
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, DataSource:="CR", _
                      DataTarget:=pFileNAme, _
                      AdditionalData:=objOrderInfo
```

The exported XML is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2015-12-09T09:34:28">
<CR>
    **<ID>1</ID>**
    <Description>Test</Description>
    <RELEASE>
        <ID>1</ID>
        **<CRID>1</CRID>**
        <Name>R2016</Name>
    </RELEASE>
    <RELEASE>
        <ID>2</ID>
        **<CRID>1</CRID>**
        <Name>R2017</Name>
    </RELEASE>
</CR>
```

Note that CRID showed several times in the XML which is practically redundant. How to remove the CRID elements from RELEASE element in XML? Thanks,

Comment: You could create a query with just the fields you need, and export that query. Much simpler.

Comment: @iDevlop - That would create a "flat" denormalized XML file which is not what the user wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to tweak the XML output after using `Application.ExportXML` you could do the initial export to a temporary XML file and then use an .xslt file like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RELEASE/CRID">
        <!-- omit by doing nothing -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and a VBA routine like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ApplyXmlTransform(sourceFile, stylesheetFile, resultFile)
    ' ref: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/transforming_xml_in_microsoft.html
    '
    ' project reference required: Microsoft XML, v4.0

    Dim source As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    Dim stylesheet As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
    Dim result As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30

    ' Load data.
    source.async = False
    source.Load sourceFile  ' source .xml file

    ' Load style sheet.
    stylesheet.async = False
    stylesheet.Load stylesheetFile  ' .xslt file

    If (source.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
        MsgBox ("Error loading source document: " & source.parseError.reason)
    Else
        If (stylesheet.parseError.errorCode <> 0) Then
            MsgBox ("Error loading stylesheet document: " & stylesheet.parseError.reason)
        Else
            ' Do the transform.
            source.transformNodeToObject stylesheet, result
            result.Save resultFile  ' resulting .xml file
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

to remove `<CRID>` from the `<RELEASE>` element.

Comment: I used a XSLT to generate the final result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how you could. After all, CRID is a field of table RELEASE:

```
<RELEASE>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <CRID>1</CRID>
    <Name>R2016</Name>
</RELEASE>
```

Comment: That's the dilemma, I want to keep it to have the relationship created, but want to get rid of it because it is duplicated information...Is it possible to filter the information in VBA after xml is created?

Comment: Well, you and I can see it, but the XML file (as is) only knows _about_ the relation, not _how_ (which field). This, in addition to the HTML-style tagging, causes XML files to bloat. But I guess you have to supply the XML file for another process out of your control. If not, you could use another format like Json or even CSV.