# MS Access xml remove foreign key in parent child relationship

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt-1.0

I found a similar question to mine with a potential answer a few days ago but I can no longer find it.

I was successful in outputting the XML I need from Access with one exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2019- 02-03T16:38:41">
<CD-Export>
  <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.9</price>
  <CD-Years-Export>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <year>1985</year>
  </CD-Years-Export>
  <CD-Years-Export>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <year>1986</year>
  </CD-Years-Export>
  <CD-Years-Export>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <year>1987</year>
  </CD-Years-Export>
</CD-Export>
```

I believe I should use an XSLT file to remove the foreign Key

```
<title>
from the <CD-Years-Export> segment
```

Can someone Please provide a sample XSLT transformation that could be used to 
remove the Foreign Key from a Child Node?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526905/omit-foreign-key-values-from-child-elements-when-exporting-from-access-to-xml

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this did not mean to edit your answer

Comment: Used the Empty Template it worked great for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider *any* of the below XSLT scripts:

- **Empty Template**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE TO REMOVE NODE -->
      <xsl:template match="CD-Years-Export/title"/>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```
- **Exclude node**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CD-Years-Export">
          <xsl:copy>
              <!-- EXCLUDE title NODE IN TREE REWRITE -->
              <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```
- **Rewrite parent node**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- WALK DOWN TREE FROM ROOT -->
      <xsl:template match="dataroot">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="CD-Export"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- COPY ALL BUT PARENT -->
      <xsl:template match="CD-Export">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='CD-Years-Export']"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="CD-Years-Export"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <!-- RE-WRITE PARENT NODE -->
      <xsl:template match="CD-Years-Export">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="year"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```
- [**Muenchian Method**](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) *(Grouping by distinct title)*

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:key name="title_key" match="CD-Years-Export" use="title"/>

      <xsl:template match="dataroot">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="CD-Export"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CD-Export">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='CD-Years-Export']"/>
              <!-- ITERATE THROUGH EACH DISTINCT title -->
              <xsl:for-each select="CD-Years-Export[generate-id() =
                                       generate-id(key('title_key', title)[1])]">
                  <!-- RE-WRITE NODE FOR EACH DISTINCT title -->
                   <xsl:for-each select="key('title_key', title)">
                      <xsl:copy>
                          <xsl:copy-of select="year"/>
                      </xsl:copy>                           
                   </xsl:for-each>                     
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```
- **Muenchian Method** *(without `xsl:for-each` using mode templates)*

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:key name="title_key" match="CD-Years-Export" use="title"/>

      <xsl:template match="dataroot">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="CD-Export"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CD-Export">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="*[name()!='CD-Years-Export']"/>
              <!-- ITERATE THROUGH EACH DISTINCT title -->
              <xsl:apply-templates select="CD-Years-Export[generate-id() =
                                            generate-id(key('title_key', title)[1])]"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CD-Years-Export">
          <!-- RE-WRITE NODE FOR EACH DISTINCT title -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('title_key', title)" mode="group"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CD-Years-Export" mode="group">
          <xsl:copy>
              <!-- RE-WRITE NODE FOR EACH DISTINCT title -->
              <xsl:copy-of select="year"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```

Comment: I do not understand your question/problem. You need original XML and an XSLT processor/library to run any of these solutions.

Comment: You are not supposed to edit *my* answer with *your* attempt. It now appears you changed your needs with *adding* keys when these answers *remove* keys. Edit your question post then I'll adjust my answer and future readers will not be confused with this thread.